# PL/SQL Object Type to XML

Tags: xml, plsql, xmltype

I am trying to Create XML from PL/SQL Object

```
<header>
     <Amount Ccy="USD">100</Amount>
</header>
```

For the above result I tried to create PL/SQL Object as shown below:-

```
create or replace type "header" as object( "Amount"  number)

DECLARE
  l_header "header";
  l_xml    xmltype;

BEGIN

  l_header := NEW "header"(100);
  l_xml    := xmltype(l_header);

  dbms_output.put_line(l_xml.getclobval);
END;




Result of above is 
<header><Amount>100</Amount></header>
```

How to include Ccy attribute in pl/sql object creation?

Comment: I am sure this can be achieved by pl/sql type, looks like something i am missing for amount tag.

Comment: Hi,Any help to get attribute and tag value using pl/sql type will be very helpful.

Comment: Hi, i came to know that we can add attribute using @ in plsql type creation. Eg. create or replace type "Amount_t" as object( "@Ccy") ; create or replace type "header" as object("Amount" "Amount_t")  This is able to give attribute but i am not able to get tag value. With this result is  <header><Amount Ccy="MMK"/></header>. How to add value to Amount Tag ??

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this different approach if it's possible for you:

```
DECLARE
  l_xml    xmltype;
BEGIN

  SELECT XMLELEMENT
   ( "header", 
      XMLELEMENT
       (
          "Amount",
          XMLATTRIBUTES
          (
            'USD' AS "Ccy"
          )
       )
   )
  INTO l_xml
  FROM dual;


  dbms_output.put_line(l_xml.getclobval);
END;
```

Comment: Hi, The actual xml is quite big with 200 tags and it will be difficult to manage using this approach. Hence, we were looking to create object and assign values to respective tag.